# new column based on two rows from consecutive days in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following problem.
I computed average temperature per country and also a difference between the actual daily temperature and the average temperature. See code below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("01", "01", "01","01", "01", "02", "02" , "03", "03","03"),
                  date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03" , "2020-01-05", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-02",  "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"),
                  temperature = c(4, 3, -2, 0.1, -3, 1.5, 12, 10, 7, 5),
                  blabla = c(23, 41, 32, 8, 50, 27, 8, 7, 6, 12)
)


library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(mean_per_country = mean(temperature))


df2$difference <- df2$temperature - df2$mean_per_country
```

Now I need to create a new column that checks if (unlimited number of) consecutive days in the same country have negative, or positive difference between the actual daily temperature and the average temperature. Is there an elegant way how can I do it in R?

Desired output is here:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(country = c("01", "01", "01","01", "01", "02", "02" , "03", "03","03"),
                         date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03" , "2020-01-05", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-02",  "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"),
                         temperature = c(4, 3, -2, 2, -3, 1.5, 12, 10, 7, 5),
                         blabla = c(23, 41, 32, 8, 50, 27, 8, 7, 6, 12),
                         mean_per_country = c(0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 6.75, 6.75, 7.33, 7.33, 7.33),
                         difference = c(3.58, 2.58, -2.42 , -0.32, -3.42 , -5.25, 5.25, 2.67, -0.333, -2.33),
                         new_column = c("hot",
                                        "hot",
                                        "", #day interrupted, therefor not "cold"
                                        "", #day interrupted, therefor not "cold"
                                        "", #day interrupted, therefor not "cold"
                                        "", 
                                        "", 
                                        "", 
                                        "cold",
                                        "cold")
                         
)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Why does country 01 have two days of hot and not 3 days of cold. Likewise, why does 03 have two days of cold and not one day of hot?

Comment: @IanCampbell Because country 01 in 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-02 has a positive `difference`. Later, 2020-01-03 and 2020-01-05 are NOT consecutive days, because 2020-01-04 is missing, therefor no `cold`. Similarly, there is no data for country 03 in 2020-01-01, therefor 2020-01-02 cannot be `hot`. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date),
          consecutive = date - lag(date) == 1,
          result = (sign(difference) == sign(lead(difference)) & lead(consecutive) |
                   (sign(difference) == sign(lag(difference)) & consecutive)),
          new_column = c("cold",NA_character_,"hot")[result * sign(difference) + 2])
# A tibble: 10 x 9
# Groups:   country [3]
   country date       temperature blabla mean_per_country difference consecutive result new_column
   <chr>   <date>           <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>  <chr>     
 1 01      2020-01-01         4       23             0.42      3.58  NA          TRUE   hot       
 2 01      2020-01-02         3       41             0.42      2.58  TRUE        TRUE   hot       
 3 01      2020-01-03        -2       32             0.42     -2.42  TRUE        FALSE  NA        
 4 01      2020-01-05         0.1      8             0.42     -0.32  FALSE       FALSE  NA        
 5 01      2020-01-07        -3       50             0.42     -3.42  FALSE       NA     NA        
 6 02      2020-01-01         1.5     27             6.75     -5.25  NA          NA     NA        
 7 02      2020-01-03        12        8             6.75      5.25  FALSE       NA     NA        
 8 03      2020-01-02        10        7             7.33      2.67  NA          NA     NA        
 9 03      2020-01-03         7        6             7.33     -0.333 TRUE        TRUE   cold      
10 03      2020-01-04         5       12             7.33     -2.33  TRUE        TRUE   cold
```

To get rid of the intermediate columns that I left there for illustration purposes, just user `select(-(consecutive:result))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the dates to `Date` class and then you can calculate the differences between dates. Then group by country and use `ifelse()` to set the values if the differences are 1:

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
df2$date = as.Date(df2$date)
diffs <- c(0,diff(df2$date))
df2 %>% group_by(country) %>%
        plyr::mutate(new_column = ifelse((difference > 0) & (diffs == 1), "hot", ifelse((difference < 0) & (diffs == 1), "cold", " ")))

> df2
   country       date temperature blabla mean_per_country difference new_column
1       01 2020-01-01         4.0     23         0.420000  3.5800000       
2       01 2020-01-02         3.0     41         0.420000  2.5800000        hot
3       01 2020-01-03        -2.0     32         0.420000 -2.4200000       cold
4       01 2020-01-05         0.1      8         0.420000 -0.3200000           
5       01 2020-01-07        -3.0     50         0.420000 -3.4200000           
6       02 2020-01-01         1.5     27         6.750000 -5.2500000           
7       02 2020-01-03        12.0      8         6.750000  5.2500000           
8       03 2020-01-02        10.0      7         7.333333  2.6666667           
9       03 2020-01-03         7.0      6         7.333333 -0.3333333       cold
10      03 2020-01-04         5.0     12         7.333333 -2.3333333       cold
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is the first row `hot`?

Comment: What should it be instead?

Comment: @VitaminB16 empty row, because there is no 2020-12-31 date with a positive `difference`

Comment: @IanCampbell I had a clash for `mutate()` function with another library. Fixed now.
@vojtam Changed that too.

Comment: @vojtam check: your `desired_df` has `hot` in the first row.